# ¿Cúal puede ser la causa del error "'numpy.float64' object is not callable", en este caso?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Dada una serie de cotizaciones, necesito  dividir la serie temporal en bloques de 253 datos y aplicar  en cada bloque la función la función que, en este ejemplo, denomino **"calcular_H(df)"**, e incluir en la lista MyHValues cada uno de los valores registrados. Lo intento de la manera siguiente.

```
# Creamos el DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def crear_df_cotiz(num_days):
    np.random.seed(100)
    dates = pd.date_range('20160104', periods=1000, freq='D')
    datos1 = pd.DataFrame(dates ,columns=['Date'])
    datos2 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['High'])
    datos3 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['Low'])
    datos4 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)), columns=['Close'])
    datos5 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['Volume'])

    df_cotiz = pd.concat([datos1,datos2,datos3,datos4, datos5],axis=1)
    df_cotiz['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cotiz['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
    df_cotiz.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
    return df_cotiz

num_days = 1000 
df_cotiz  = crear_df_cotiz(num_days)

# Calculamos H
def calcular_H(df):
    return df**2

# Recuperamos en MyHValues los valores calculados
""" Creamos una lista denominada MyHValues para guardar en ella los valores de H"""
MyHValues=[]
Bloque_Datos = 253
Start = 0
End = Bloque_Datos

while Start < while Start < df.shape[0]:
    df['H1'] = df_cotiz['Close'][Start:End]
    MyHValues.append(pruebas(df_cotiz['H1']))
    Start += Bloque_Datos
    End += Bloque_datos


# Mostramos la media de todas las observaciones.
print ('\n Media del Exponente H  : {:.2f}'.format(mean(MyHValues)))
```

Me devuelve el error siguiente:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2747/2497110246.py in <module>
     17 while Start < df.shape[0]:
     18     df['H1'] = df['Close'][Start:End]
---> 19     MyHValues.append(hurst(df['H1']))
     20     Start += Bloque_Datos
     21     End += Bloque_datos

/tmp/ipykernel_2747/1191531528.py in hurst(ts)
      7 
      8     # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
----> 9     tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]
     10 
     11     # Use a linear fit to estimate the Hurst Exponent

/tmp/ipykernel_2747/1191531528.py in <listcomp>(.0)
      7 
      8     # Calculate the array of the variances of the lagged differences
----> 9     tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]
     10 
     11     # Use a linear fit to estimate the Hurst Exponent

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

1
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Una comparación aplicada a una columna de un dataframe no devuelve un booleano, sino una serie de ellos. Eso ocurre en tu caso en `while Start < df_cotiz['Close'][Start:End]` Lo que ocurre es que se compara el valor de `Start` con cada elemento del dataframe seleccionado por `df_cotiz['Close'][Start:End]` y se obtiene una serie de valores `True` o `False`, según cada valor sea mayor o no a `Start`. Pero claro, en un `while` no vale pasarle una ristra de booleanos. Se necesita solo uno. ¿Qué quieres expresar, que **todos** ellos sean mayores o que **al menos uno**  lo sea?

Comment: En realidad no creo que quisieras ninguno de los dos casos. No entiendo qué se pretende con ese `while` ¿puedes aclararlo?

Comment: Efectivamente, tengo un error en el while, que debe quedar 'while Start < df.shape[0]:'. De todas formas, con esta corrección, no consigo mi objetivo:  dividir la serie temporal en bloques de 253 datos, aplicar 
en cada bloque la función del Exponente de Hurst, e incluir en la lista MyHValues cada uno de 
los valores registrados, Procedo a modificar la pregunta incluyendo el nuevo error reportado. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Asegúrate de que en tu notebook no hayas definido por algún sitio una variable llamada `sqrt`. Prueba a hacer `print(sqrt)` a ver qué sale. Predigo que te saldrá un número, y por eso falla, pues `sqrt` debe ser una función. Al asignarle un número has sobreescrito el valor que debería tener de `from math import sqrt` (o tal vez se trata de una variable llamada `std`, o bien `substract`, ya que esas son las funciones que intentas llamar en la línea que está dando error)

Comment: En mi programa real, la función, con los valores de la lista que le entrego, calcula un índice (un valor). He definido mal la función del ejemplo, que podría ser return df['Close'].sum(), es decir retornar la suma de los 253 valores de cada serie. Con esta modificación, cambia el error que es ahora ''function' object is not subscriptable. Voy a echar 'otra pensada', antes de hacer nuevas modificaciones en la pregunta y, si encuentro la solución, reportarla en esta página.

Comment: El error lo señala en la línea 'MyHValues.append(calcular_H['H1'])

Comment: Claro, si `calcular_H` es una función, tienes que llamarla usando `()`, y no tratarla como una lista o dataframe usando `[]`. Lo que ya no sé es lo que tendrías que pasarle como parámetro porque con tanto cambio me he perdido.

Comment: Gracias. Efectivamente, ese es otro ferror . Voy a repensarlo todo.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez corregidos los errores detectados, el script definito, queda así.

```
# Creamos el DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def crear_df_cotiz(num_days):
    np.random.seed(100)
    dates = pd.date_range('20160104', periods=1000, freq='D')
    datos1 = pd.DataFrame(dates ,columns=['Date'])
    datos2 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['High'])
    datos3 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['Low'])
    datos4 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)), columns=['Close'])
    datos5 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['Volume'])

    df_cotiz = pd.concat([datos1,datos2,datos3,datos4, datos5],axis=1)
    df_cotiz['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cotiz['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
    df_cotiz.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
    return df_cotiz

num_days = 1000 
df_cotiz  = crear_df_cotiz(num_days)

# Calculamos H
def calcular_H(df):
    return df.sum()

# Recuperamos en MyHValues los valores calculados
""" Creamos una lista denominada MyHValues para guardar en ella los valores de H"""
MyHValues=[]
Bloque_Datos = 253
Start = 0
End = Bloque_Datos

while Start < df.shape[0]:
    df['H1'] = df_cotiz['Close'][Start:End]
    MyHValues.append(calcular_H(df['H1']))
    Start += Bloque_Datos
    End += Bloque_Datos


# Mostramos la media de todas las observaciones.
print ('\n Media del Exponente H  : {:.2f}'.format(mean(MyHValues)))
```

Gracias por la ayuda